# FIFO based stock inventory valuation in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a stock transaction table like this:

```
Item   Date         TxnType Qty  Price
ABC   01-April-2012   IN    200 750.00
ABC   05-April-2012   OUT   100     
ABC   10-April-2012   IN     50 700.00
ABC   16-April-2012   IN     75 800.00
ABC   25-April-2012   OUT   175     
XYZ   02-April-2012   IN    150 350.00
XYZ   08-April-2012   OUT   120     
XYZ   12-April-2012   OUT    10     
XYZ   24-April-2012   IN     90 340.00
```

I need the value of the inventory for each item in FIFO (First in first out) meaning the first purchased item should be consumed first.
The output stock valuation of the above data is:

```
Item  Qty      Value
ABC   50    40000.00
XYZ   110   37600.00
```

Please help me to get the solution.

Comment: Can you please explain you output what numbers should be summed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surprisingly difficult to get right. I suspect it would be easier using SQL Server 2012 which supports running sums in windowing functions. Anyhow:

```
declare @Stock table (Item char(3) not null,[Date] datetime not null,TxnType varchar(3) not null,Qty int not null,Price decimal(10,2) null)
insert into @Stock(Item ,  [Date] ,        TxnType, Qty,  Price) values
('ABC','20120401','IN',    200, 750.00),
('ABC','20120405','OUT',   100 ,null  ),
('ABC','20120410','IN',     50, 700.00),
('ABC','20120416','IN',     75, 800.00),
('ABC','20120425','OUT',   175, null  ),
('XYZ','20120402','IN',    150, 350.00),
('XYZ','20120408','OUT',   120 ,null  ),
('XYZ','20120412','OUT',    10 ,null  ),
('XYZ','20120424','IN',     90, 340.00);

;WITH OrderedIn as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY [DATE]) as rn
    from @Stock
    where TxnType = 'IN'
), RunningTotals as (
    select Item,Qty,Price,Qty as Total,0 as PrevTotal,rn from OrderedIn where rn = 1
    union all
    select rt.Item,oi.Qty,oi.Price,rt.Total + oi.Qty,rt.Total,oi.rn
    from
        RunningTotals rt
            inner join
        OrderedIn oi
            on
                rt.Item = oi.Item and
                rt.rn = oi.rn - 1
), TotalOut as (
    select Item,SUM(Qty) as Qty from @Stock where TxnType='OUT' group by Item
)
select
    rt.Item,SUM(CASE WHEN PrevTotal > out.Qty THEN rt.Qty ELSE rt.Total - out.Qty END * Price)
from
    RunningTotals rt
        inner join
    TotalOut out
        on
            rt.Item = out.Item
where
    rt.Total > out.Qty
group by rt.Item
```

The first observation is that we don't need to do anything special for `OUT` transactions - we just need to know the total quantity. That's what the `TotalOut` CTE calculates. The first two CTEs work with `IN` transactions, and compute what "interval" of stock each represents - change the final query to just `select * from RunningTotals` to get a feel for that.

The final `SELECT` statement finds rows which haven't been completely exhausted by outgoing transactions, and then decides whether it's the whole quantity of that incoming transaction, or whether that is the transaction that straddles the outgoing total.

Comment: Dear @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks for the great solution. I was using cursors for doing this and it was taking lot of time. Can you kindly suggest how to do the same using LIFO model? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Nagesh - the would be significantly more complex - not got anything off the top of my head - since `in` 20, at price A, `out` 10, `in` 20 at price B, `out` 10 would presumably leave you with 20, composed of 10 at price `A` and 10 at price `B`. You can't make the simplifying assumption I did above that all `out`s are equal.

Comment: Dear @Damien_The_Unbeliever one more issue. The SQL you have provided is showing stock values if both IN and OUT transactions exist. If I have only IN it is not showing the result of those items. Kindly modify this.

Comment: @Nagesh - change the `inner join` at the bottom to a `left join`, and each reference to `out.Qty` to `COALESCE(out.Qty,0)` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use detail transaction table for this.
Like Stock,StockDetail,StockDetailTransaction.
In this StockDetailTransaction table contain FIFO Entry for Stock.
When Item In/Out that time add record in StockDetailTransaction.