# Calculate Profit Based on First-In, First-Out Pricing

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Say I have purchase and sales data for some SKUs:

```
po_id | sku | purchase_date    | price | qty
----------------------------------------------
    1 | 123 | 2013-01-01 12:25 | 20.15 |   5
    2 | 123 | 2013-05-01 15:45 | 17.50 |   3
    3 | 123 | 2013-05-02 12:00 | 15.00 |   1
    4 | 456 | 2013-06-10 16:00 | 60.00 |   7

sale_id | sku | sale_date        | price | qty
------------------------------------------------
      1 | 123 | 2013-01-15 11:00 | 30.00 |   1
      2 | 123 | 2013-01-20 14:00 | 28.00 |   3
      3 | 123 | 2013-05-10 15:00 | 25.00 |   2
      4 | 456 | 2013-06-11 12:00 | 80.00 |   1
```

How can I find the sales margin via SQL, assuming they are sold in the order they were purchased? E.g, the margin for sku 123 is

```
30*1 + 28*3 + 25*2 - 20.15*5 - 17.50*1
```

with 2 purchased at 17.50 and 1 purchased at 15.00 left unsold.

Comment: Can you clarify - one table is the buy or wholesale price and the other is the retail sales data? So you're setting an active wholesale price on `5/1` of `$17.50 / 3`? Then you want to compare the active price *at that time* against retail sales data for what was the active period?

Comment: It will also help to know which RDBMS product you're using. A problem like this is certainly going to benefit from vendor-specific SQL features (e.g. CTE, partitioning, etc.)

Comment: @Yuck, correct, this is wholesale buy data and retail sales data. We have this data in both SQL Server and MySQL, but a general SQL solution would be best if possible.

Comment: The solution to this will be very similar if not identical to a first-in-first-out (FIFO) securities pricing problem. Have you looked for something like that?

Comment: @Yuck No, anything you can point me to?

Comment: You could start with this, although admittedly I haven't read very deep into it to determine if it's a perfect fit for your problem. Hopefully it gives you some idea for the direction you need to go: http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/1961/the-fifo-stock-inventory-sql-problem.html

Comment: Also these SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327741/fifo-based-stock-inventory-valuation-in-sql-server and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204136/first-in-first-out-fifo-inventory-costing

Comment: I hate doing it, but do you care if the answer has a cursor? I'm sure there is a very complex query you could write to get the answer, but I'm not sure it would actually be more efficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question.  The approach that I'm taking is to calculate the total sales.  Then calculate cumulative purchases, and combine them with special logic to get the right arithmetic for the combination:

```
select s.sku,
       (MarginPos - SUM(case when s.totalqty < p.cumeqty - p.qty then p.price * p.qty
                             when s.totalqty between p.cumeqty - p.qty and p.qty
                             then s.price * (s.totalqty - (p.cumeqty - p.qty))
                             else 0
                        end)
       ) as Margin
from (select s.sku, SUM(price*qty) as MarginPos, SUM(qty) as totalqty
      from sales s
     ) s left outer join
     (select p.*,
             (select SUM(p.qty) from purchase p2 where p2.sku = p.sku and p2.sale_id <= p.sale_id
             ) as cumeqty
      from purchase s
     )
     on s.sku = p.sku
group by s.sku, MarginPos
```

Note:  I haven't tested this query so it might have syntax errors.

Comment: For starters mysql doesn't have `full outer join`.  `union` is one way to get around this.

Comment: @ebyrob . . . Point taken.  The full outer join isn't even needed, so I switched it to a simple inner join.  It was there just because I was worried about missing skus.

Comment: I had to fix up the case statement to get what I wanted, but this seems to work. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6177/20/0

Comment: Note: The expense SUM can be simplified to: `SUM(price * GREATEST(LEAST(qty, totalqty - (cumeqty - qty)), 0))` no need for a case statement.

Answer (score 1):

setting ambient

```
    declare @purchased table (id int,sku int,dt date,price money,qty int)
    declare @sold table (id int,sku int,dt date,price money,qty int)

    insert into @purchased
    values( 1 , 123 , '2013-01-01 12:25' , 20.15 ,   5)
        ,(2 , 123 , '2013-05-01 15:45' , 17.50 ,   3)
        ,(3 , 123 , '2013-05-02 12:00' , 15.00 ,   1)
        ,(4 , 456 , '2013-06-10 16:00' , 60.00 ,   7)

    insert into @sold
    values(1 , 123 , '2013-01-15 11:00' , 30.00 ,   1)
          ,(2 , 123 , '2013-01-20 14:00' , 28.00 ,   3)
          ,(3 , 123 , '2013-05-10 15:00' , 25.00 ,   2)
          ,(4 , 456 , '2013-06-11 12:00' , 80.00 ,   1)
```

a sqlserver solution should be...

```
    with cte_sold as (select sku,sum(qty) as qty, SUM(qty*price) as total_value
                      from @sold
                      group by sku
                      )
    ,cte_purchased as (select id,sku,price,qty 
                       from @purchased
                       union all select id,sku,price,qty-1 as qty 
                       from cte_purchased
                       where qty>1
                    )
    ,cte_purchased_ordened as(select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by sku order by id,qty) as buy_order
                                    ,sku
                                    ,price
                                    ,1 as qty
                              from cte_purchased 
    )

    select P.sku
          ,S.total_value - SUM(case when P.buy_order <= S.qty then P.price else 0 end) as margin
    from cte_purchased_ordened P
    left outer join cte_sold S
    on S.sku = P.sku
    group by P.sku,S.total_value,S.qty
```

resultset achieved

```
    sku margin
    123 45,75
    456 20,00
```

same result for sku 123 example in the problem description...

30*1 + 28*3 + 25*2 - 20.15*5 - 17.50*1 = 45.75

Answer (score 0):

This is really horrible since it changes a MySQL variable in the queries, but it kind of works (and takes 3 statements):

```
select
  @income := sum(price*qty) as income,
  @num_bought := cast(sum(qty) as unsigned) as units
from sale
where sku = 123
;

select
  @expense := sum(expense) as expense,
  sum(units) as units
from (select
  price * least(@num_bought, qty) as expense,
  least(@num_bought, qty) as units,
  @num_bought := @num_bought - least(@num_bought, qty)
from purchase
where sku = 123 and @num_bought > 0
order by po_id
) as a
;

select round(@income - @expense, 2) as profit_margin;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is Oracle query but should work in any SQL. It is simplified and does not include all necessary calculations. You can add them yourself. You will see slightly diff totals as 17.50*3 not 17.50*1:

```
SELECT po_sku AS sku, po_total, sale_total, (po_total-sale_total) Margin
  FROM
 (
  SELECT SUM(price*qty) po_total, sku po_sku
    FROM stack_test
  GROUP BY sku
 ) a,
 (
  SELECT SUM(price*qty) sale_total, sku sale_sku
    FROM stack_test_sale
   GROUP BY sku
 ) b
 WHERE po_sku = sale_sku
 /

SKU     PO_TOTAL    SALE_TOTAL  MARGIN
---------------------------------------------------
123     168.25      164         4.25
456     420         80          340
```

You can also add partition by SKU if required:

```
SUM(price*qty) OVER (PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY sku)
```

Comment: They want the margin for inventory sold in a first in first out sequence and they want to know the remaining inventory. The don't want the remaining inventory considered in the margin results and they want to know the inventory they have left and how much they paid for those particular units.

Comment: @Love2Learn - And? Why would I break my head to calc all that...? I shown the simple way to do any calc. Let user do the math. And what is the sequence? It was not mentioned in post. All I saw was a formula that I followed. Gordon is great, I really think so, but can you even read that? Why over complicate?