# Update oldest rows based on sum of column

Tags: mysql, sql

We are having a following MySQL table to maintain user credits.

```
id   user    credits      expiry        status
-----------------------------------------
1     A       1.2        somedatetime    0
2     A       4.4        somedatetime    0  
3     A       5.0        somedatetime    0  
4     B       1.0        somedatetime    0  
5     B       2.4        somedatetime    0  
6     C       7.8        somedatetime    0
```

Whenever user makes a purchase, we deduct the amount from the available credits. To be fair to user, the credits with nearest expiry will be consumed first and so on. We will also update the status to mark row as consumed.

For example, if user A makes a purchase of $2, $1.2 will be debited from id 1 and remaining $0.8 from id 2 and so on. So Table will now look like

```
id   user    credits      expiry        status
-----------------------------------------
1     A       0.0        somedatetime    1
2     A       3.6        somedatetime    1  
3     A       5.0        somedatetime    0  
4     B       1.0        somedatetime    0  
5     B       2.4        somedatetime    0  
6     C       7.8        somedatetime    0
```

So far we have been doing it with brute-force approach. Any idea suggestion how to do it more efficiently in minimum or single query.

**Update**: since someone asked about our current brute-force approach, it's iterating each row from the oldest and updating till the purchase amount is covered, which is very inefficient.

Thanks

Comment: Similar questions have been asked.

Comment: @Strawberry: Post the link please

Comment: What do you mean by 'brute force approach'?

Comment: @shadow reading rows one by one and update till the purchase amount is covered.

Comment: Similar topic here because you want to calculate based on FIFO method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633720/calculate-profit-based-on-first-in-first-out-pricing

Comment: _of $2, $1.2 will be debited from id 1 and remaining $0.6_  I am not that good in math, but I have remaining **0.8**

Comment: @Alex Yes, I just have to double check because tought my solution was wrong.

Comment: @Yusuf that's not the brute force approach, that's what MySQL would do as well. This is the only approach. You can write a query that updates rows in a particular order and using user variables, you can influence the new value. However, your query will be complex, while the application logic with a loop will be a lots simpler.

Comment: @Alex, Juan my bad, updated the post.

Comment: @Shadow, thanks for the insight. yes query is indeed getting complex, just wondering any specific advantage of it apart from saving on multiple  connections for each update if it's done in application.

Answer (score 3):

Using variables you calculate the totals credits. Run the inner query so you learn what is beign calculate first.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/UHG81082)**

```
UPDATE customer c
JOIN (
        SELECT cu.`id`, 
               cu.`user`, 
               `credits`, `expiry`, `status`,        
               @total := IF(@customer = cu.`user`, @total := @total  + `credits`, `credits`) as cumulative_total,
               @customer := cu.`user` as user_current,
               `credit_used`
        FROM customer cu 
        CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @customer := '', @total := 0 ) t
        JOIN credits
          ON cu.`user` = credits.`user`
        ORDER BY cu.`id`
     ) t
   ON c.`id` = t.`id`
SET c.credits = CASE WHEN c.credits <= t.credit_used THEN 0
                                                     ELSE t.cumulative_total - credit_used
                END,
    c.status =  CASE WHEN c.credits <= t.credit_used THEN 1
                                                     ELSE 0
                END;
```

My test Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
    (`id` int, `user` varchar(1), `credits` double, `expiry` int, `status` int)
;

INSERT INTO customer
    (`id`, `user`, `credits`, `expiry`, `status`)
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 1.2, 1, 0),
    (2, 'A', 4.4, 2, 0),
    (3, 'A', 5.0, 3, 0),
    (4, 'B', 1.0, 4, 0),
    (5, 'B', 2.4, 5, 0),
    (6, 'C', 7.8, 6, 0)
;

CREATE TABLE credits
    (`id` int, `user` varchar(1), `credit_used` double)
;

INSERT INTO credits
    (`id`, `user`, `credit_used`)
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 2.0),
    (2, 'B', 3.4)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/485673/1

```
SET @amount = 2;
UPDATE t1
JOIN (
  SELECT t2.id, 
    IF(@amount=0,t2.credits, IF(@amount>t2.credits,0,t2.credits-@amount)) credits,
    IF(@amount>=t2.credits,@amount := @amount-t2.credits, 0)
  FROM (
    SELECT id, credits
    FROM t1
    WHERE credits>0 AND `user`='A'
    ORDER BY expiry ASC
  ) t2
           ) t
ON t1.id = t.id
SET t1.credits=t.credits
WHERE t1.user = 'A';
```